# Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem. What can we say about $c$ with more information.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

My questions is about Cauchy's Mean Value theorem which states:

> If functions f and g are both continuous on the closed interval [a,b],
>   and differentiable on the open interval (a, b), then there exists some
>   c ∈ (a,b), such that
>   \begin{align*}
> (f(b)-f(a))g'(c)=(g(b)-g(a))f'(c)
> \end{align*}

From my understanding $c$ is not that trivial to find and it might not even be unique. 
Here are is my questions? For $f \neq g$

**1)** Under what conditions on $g$ and $ f$ is $c$ unique? For example, is monotonicity or concavity enough?

**2)** If we give more information on $g$ and $f$. 
Can we say more about the location of $c$ in the range $(a,b)$? For example, say that $g$ and $f$ are non-negative and $g'',f''> 0$, what can we say then? ** 
For example, is it true if $f$ and $g$ are concave then
$ c \in( \frac{b+a}{2},b)$

I skimmed through several reference but wasn't able to find anything concrete about c based on properties of $f$ and $g$?

Thank you for any help in advance. Also, any references would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** As pointed out by @LeonAragones monotonicity of $f,g$ is not enuogh to guarantee uniquens of $c$.

** Edit:** Please the answer to the first part of the question by @san.

Comment: if the derivatives are montonous and continuous what happens ?

Comment: @Maman ok. I think it's uniqueness. Right?

Comment: Not really. Take $f, g \colon [0,1] \to [0,1]$, $x \mapsto x$. Any $c$ will do.

Comment: @LeonAragones I see. Thanks. So, when is $c$ unique?

Comment: @LeonAragones What if $f,g$ are concave? That is $g''<0$ and $f''<0$.

Comment: @LeonAragones In your example $f,g$ is the same function, right? Don't we need $f$ and $g$ to be different functions?

Comment: @Boby No. It holds for any two functions, so in particular it holds for $f = g$

Comment: @Ant So, in ordeder to gurarantee uniquess I have to impose that $f$ and $g$ are not the same?

Comment: No. I just pointed out that the counterexample provided by @LeonAragones works, because both $f$ and $g$ are monotonous in this case. You may ask what happens when $f \neq g$ and they are both monotnous, but I doubt this will ensure uniqueness (just a gut feeling. Experience tells me that it's unlikely that the condition $f \neq g$ is going to change anything). I don't know the answer to your question on the spot, maybe tomorrow I'll think about it :)

Comment: Dear @Ant thanks. I would be very gratuful if you would get back to me.

Comment: Note that, with the normal (not Cauchy) mean value theorem, the limit of the location of 'c' as the size of the interval goes to zero is exactly the mid-point of the interval (if $f''(a)$ is non-zero). The proof of this, given in the following question, may help you to find an analogue for the result with the Cauchy mean value theorem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2175922/limiting-behaviour-of-mean-value-theorem-theta-to-frac12-as-h-to-0 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The points $c$ depend on the function $h(x):=(g(b)-g(a))f(x)-(f(b)-f(a))g(x)$. 
They are the points where $h'(c)=0$. So concavity should be required for $h$, not for $f,g$. For example, take $a=0$, $b=6\pi$, $f(x)=x^2+1$, $g(x)=x^2+1-sin(x)$. Then $f,g,f'',g''$ are positive on the interval, however, since $h(x)=(6\pi)^2 sin(x)$, we have $c_0,\dots,c_6$ with $c_k:=(2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$ such that $h'(c_k)=0$.

So, if $h''(x)>0$ for all $x$, or $h''(x)<0$ for all $x$, then the solution is unique, or more general, if $h$ is convex or concave, the solution is unique.

With respect to the second question, the answer is no, we can't say anything about the location of $c$.  "is it true if f and g are concave then $c\in (\frac{b+a}{2},b)$?" No, for example, take $f=-x^2$, $g=-1/x-x$, $a=\frac 1{10}$ and $b=10$. Then $f,g$ are concave (even $h$ is concave), but the unique solution $c=1\notin (\frac{b+a}{2},b)=(5\frac{1}{20},10)$.

Comment: Thanks. About the frist question: your explanation is really good thank you. About the second question: what if we assume that $f,g>0$ and $h$ is concave. Can we say something then about the location of $c$?

Comment: You can start with any function $h_1$ such that $h_1(b)=0=h_1(a)$. Then add any function $t(x)$ such that $t(b)\ne t(a)$. Then $f:=h_1+t$ and $g:=t$ satisfy $$h(x)=(g(b)−g(a))f(x)−(f(b)−f(a))g(x)=(t(b)-t(a))h_1(x) $$ so the derivative of $h_1$ and $h$ are zero at the same points. You can choose $t$ such that $t$ and $t+h$ are concave or convex, or monotone increasing or monotone decreasing, or positive or negative.

Comment: If $h$ is concave or convex, then $c$ can be at any place in the interval.