# Uniqueness of $c$ in mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The mean value theorem says that

> If $f(x)$ is continuous on the closed interval $x\in [a,b]$ and
>   differentiable on open interval $(a,b)$ then 
>       there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that 
>           \begin{align*}
>          f(b)-f(a)=f'(c) (b-a) 
>        \end{align*}

**My question 1:** When is $c$  unique?

**My question 2:** Can we pin point location of $c$ more accurately ?

**My thoughts on the first question:**

It is enough to have that $f(x)$ is strictly monotone. That is $f'(x)>0$ or $f'(x)<0$ for all $x \in (a,b)$.

I think this can be shown by contradiction suppose there exists anther $c_1$ bu then 
\begin{align*}
f'(c_1)=f'(c)
\end{align*}
which is a contradiction. 
Is this reasoning correct?

**My thoughts on the second question**
I think if $f(x)$ is convex and strictly decreasing then we can improve $c \in (a,b)$ to $c\in (a, \frac{b+a}{2})$. 
Right?

Is question is related to something I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317452/cauchys-mean-value-theorem-what-can-we-say-about-c-with-more-information).

Comment: As it is, the first reasoning is not correct. You need $f'$ strictly monotone for that argument (i.e. $f$ either strictly convex or strictly concave). For instance, $a=0,\ b=\pi, f(x)=\cos x$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Yes. You are right? I see it now.

Comment: For a related question with a similar motivation (particularly for your second question), see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2175922/limit-of-theta-in-mean-value-theorem-as-h-to-0 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ad 1: You need that $f'$ is strictly monotonic.

ad 2: No. If $f$ is strictly decreasing and convex, we can still have $c$ arbitrarily close to $b$. Just pick a point $(c,y)$ with $f(b)<y<\frac{(c-a)f(b)+(b-c)f(a)}{b-a}$ and verify that you can join the three points with convex and decreasing arcs.

Comment: So, regarding ad 2.  Can put better bounds on $c$ under some conditions?

Answer (score 1):

If you assume the second derivative $f''(x)$ is tightly bounded (i.e. $|f''(x)| <\epsilon$ for some small $\epsilon$, valid for $a \leq x \leq b$), then the values of $f'(a)(b-a)$ and $f'(b)(b-a)$ versus the value $f(b) - f(a)$ will dictate a potential lower bound on how far away from $a$ or $b$ you have to travel in order for it to be possible to get the desired $f'(c)(b-a) = f(b) - f(a)$. Basically because as you move away by distance $\delta$ from either $a$ or $b$, the most the derivative $f'(c)$ can change from either $f'(a)$ or $f'(b)$ is $\epsilon \delta $.